# Google Sheets Advanced Google Services URL Shortener 403 Error: Forbidden

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-403, url-shortener

I am trying to create a small application in in Google Sheets to sorten URLs on my personal google account. I am using the following code which I found here: [Google Sheets Function to get a shortened URL (from Bit.ly or goo.gl etc.)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76050/google-sheets-function-to-get-a-shortened-url-from-bit-ly-or-goo-gl-etc)

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("Shorten")
    .addItem("Go !!","rangeShort")
    .addToUi()  
}

function rangeShort() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    //var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});
    var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: 'www.google.com'});
    output.push([url.id]);
  }
  range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);
}
```

I created a new Google Cloud Project and enabled the URL shortener API in the project and on the Google sheet. The problem is that when I try and run the code I get an err on the line: `var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: 'www.google.com'});`

> error 403, message:forbidden

when i try an execute the rangeShort() function. I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas would be most appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, like Ruben mentioned, [Google has moved away from their URL shortener](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html). So after much research ans testing here is the solution:

## Step 1

Migrate Google Cloud Project over to Firebase or create a new Firebase Project. See steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/url-shortener)

## Step 2

Create a dummy project in order to create a base URL for the shortening. See [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBGKT6W4vyg)

## Step 3

Get the [Web API Key from your new Firebase Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest?authuser=0) (not the app you just created)

## Step 4

Check the left side menu on the screen and navigate to Grow->Dynamic Links. You should see the new application you created and a URL at the top of the application. This will become the base of the new shortened URLs.

## Step 5

Create the code in Google Apps Script inside the code builder from within Google Sheets. Here is the code that worked for me (I passed the url into this function) (This code is based on the answer found [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76050/google-sheets-function-to-get-a-shortened-url-from-bit-ly-or-goo-gl-etc)):

```
function api_call(url){
  var req='https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=[YOUR PROJECT WEB API KEY FROM STEP 3]';
  var formData = {
    "longDynamicLink": "[YOUR APPLICATION URL BASE FROM STEP 4]?link=" + url,
    "suffix" : {
      "option" : "UNGUESSABLE" 
    }
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(formData)

  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(req, options);
  var res=JSON.parse(response);

  return res.shortLink;
}
```

## Additional Information

1. [Documentation on Creating Dynamic Links in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest?authuser=0)
2. [Documentation on using UrlFetchApp() in Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: What about the use use of http on the long URL? Is it required?

Comment: The short link base from firebase is https, i didn't check just http.

Answer (score 1):

If the url shortener service was used in your project before March 30,2018

Instead of

```
www.google.com
```

use

```
https://www.google.com
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/insert

but if your project was created on or after March 30, 2018

From https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/

> Starting March 30, 2018, we will be turning down support for goo.gl URL shortener. Please see this [blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/transitioning-google-url-shortener.html) for detailed timelines and alternatives.

Just to be clear, please note, from the linked blog post:

> **For developers**
>
> Starting May 30, 2018, only projects that have accessed URL Shortener
>   APIs before today can create short links.

Comment: changed to `https://www.google.com`, but still doesn't work...

I suspect that is because they have moved to firebase?

If so, any idea how to complete the same function with firebase? I can't seem to find an answer b/c it's so new

Comment: @alutz33 Have you read the blog post about the turning down of goo.gl?

Comment: Yeah, i did see that, trying to migrate over, but there doesn't yet seem to be native support for firebase

Answer (score 0):

I can attest to @alutz's answer here with a small addition/correction to their code.

Use encodeURIcomponent() for the input url while assigning it to the Long Dynamic Link in case you have more than one custom parameters.

```
"longDynamicLink": "[YOUR APPLICATION URL BASE FROM STEP 4]?link=" + encodeURIcomponent(url),
```

This allowed me to pass in multiple arguments for my telegram bot like chat_id, text and parse_mode.